# Excel countif not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

My forumla is as follows `=COUNTIFS(H4:H700,"Jacob",H4:H700,"Tobi",H4:H700,"refresh")`

within the range of H4:h700, I have various different text strings. I only want to count when the text strings shown in the formula above appear in this range.

When entering this formula into a cell, say "I2" (which is outside the table), the result is 0. I can confirm that the text strings I want to query are definitely in this range.

Note, the formula in J2 works perfectly `=COUNTIF(H4:H986,"USER INSTALLED")`,

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this:
=COUNTIFS(H4:H700,"=Jacob",H4:H700,"=Tobi",H4:H700,"=refresh")

Comment: No change. Adding the = sign still results in 0. Can I use an OR statement in a situation like this? see my edit to the OP, the formula in J2 which is set up the same way works fine.

Comment: I see, yes. You need to use OR in this case. I would suggest. assuming you only have 3 variables, you simply make 3 IF statements and add them, =IF(H4:H700,"=Jacob")+IF(H4:H700,"=Tobi")+...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COUNTIFS is AND not OR so it is looking for one cell that has everything you are asking.

You want this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(H4:H700,{"Jacob","Tobi","refresh"}))
```

Comment: This answer is better than my suggestion :)

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I figured I was on the right track earlier since I was playing with =SUM and =COUNTIF statements. Didn't think to nest them together, and I would've never thought to try brackets.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose it is the same in principle but with less typing